# Часы на javascript

Tags: javascript

Как написать на javascript  цифровые часы,но не обычные,а со своей "системой счисления", т.е в которой 1 час по длительности это уже не 1 час (в привычных наших часах).Чисто для примера , 1 час  = 40 наших минут, и др  соответствия по минутам и секундам.Как это реализовать?

Comment: Теперь осталось узнать сколько в сутках часов, а лучше в минутах. По сути в часах и так своя система счисления: 60-ричная, или 12-ричная, на выбор. Как бы вы сейчас это реализовали?

Comment: @Leonid: лучше узнать сколько обычных миллисекунд в "необычных" ;-)

Comment: @UModeL: У меня проблемы не с математикой а с самим ЯП, т.е я незнаю, как выделить из функции date ,отдельно минуты, секунды и часы в отдельные переменные,чтобы потом их преобразовать